# R: Not able to save the plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, save

I am generating a plot which I am able to see in the RMarkdown output but whenever I am trying to save it, I am getting just a blank(white) image. I am just adding following two lines before and after plot

```
png("Output.png")
#Plot code
dev.off()
```

It was working. And suddenly it stopped working. Can someone help me on this??

## edit

When I do it with `pdf`

```
pdf("output.pdf")
#plot code
dev.off()
```

I am getting error as:

```
There was error opening this document. This document cannot be opened because it has no pages.
```

Thanks.

Comment: This should work, the problem is probably in the `plot code` section. Please create a reproducible example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. My guess is that you are using either `lattice` or `ggplot2` and that you need to call `print` on the code that generates the figure.

Comment: I suspect you have a device opened. Run `dev.off()` until you get a message `Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes, you were right I was using `ggplot`. And I needed to call `print` to get the image. Thanks.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, you can accept it to show everyone else that this has been solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to plot doesn't actually produce plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730030/call-to-plot-doesnt-actually-produce-plot) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811106/cant-print-to-pdf-ggplot-charts/4811119#4811119 and 14 more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments I gather that I was right, you need to print the resulting `ggplot2` object in order to show the plot, see also R FAQ 7.22.

Comment: Hi, this happens to me even without using ggplot2 (I'm using base graphics "boxplot" function). Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @AHegde this problem is not related to this one as the boxplot function does not use `grid` graphics. Please create a new question which includes a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).